# replace specific keys in a deeply embedded json file

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a json file (origin.json) generated locally, I'd like to replace some keys in this origin.json and generate a remote.json so that I could send it to a remote server following it's endpoint payload format.

My origin.json is large and deeply embedded , I could iterate each keys and replace those I need to. But I am wondering is there an efficient and fancy tool could do the same ? Something like jq ?

Below are my embedded json

```
{
        "timeoutMs": 3000,
        "requestTopic": "local-cron",
        "searchQuery": {
            "checkin": "2023-01-10",
            "checkout": "2023-01-11",
            "numberRoomsNeeded": 0,
            "adultsTotal": 2,
            "childrenTotal": 0,
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "requestContext": {
            "userId": 666666666,
            "userAuthLevel": 2,
            "isUserstar": true,
            "visitorCc1": "cn",
            "trafficSourceId": 0,
            "siteTypeId": 9,
            "detectedUserType": "normal",
            "travelPurpose": 2,
            "affiliateId": 12345,
            "languageCode": "en-us",
            "currency": "CNY",
            "siteType": 1,
            "serverRole": "cron",
            "action": "bp",
            "visitorIdentifier": [
                {
                    "type": "id-single",
                    "uvi": "00000000000000000000000"
                },
                {
                    "type": "user-identity",
                    "uvi": "66666666"
                },
                {
                    "type": "user",
                    "uvi": "77777777777"
                }
            ],
            "isInternal": true,
            "enableExperiments": true,
            "shouldTrackRequestInExperiments": true,
            "starSettings": {
                "isUserstar": true,
                "isUserstarControlGroup": false,
                "canStarUserSeeFreeBreakfast": true,
                "canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade": true,
                "starTier": 5,
                "topstarBenefit": "",
                "isRightstar": true,
                "starDynamicPricing": {
                    "canSeestarDynamicPricingLevel3": true
                },
                "canStarUserSeeFreeCleaningFee": true,
                "starVipSettings": [
                    {
                        "eligible": true,
                        "benefitName": "no_et",
                        "programType": "PriceMatchTrial",
                        "percentage": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            "isCsRelocationMode": false,
            "tripValueContext": {},
            "visitorCountryRegion": "sh",
            "paymentTiming": 1,
            "includeConditional": false
        },
        "showDebug": false,
        "hits": [
            {
                "hhhhid": 8228082,
                "ppblock": {
                    "allMatchingBlocks": [
                        {
                            "blockId": 1,
                            "rawBlock": {
                                "occupancy": 2,
                                "price": 34425,
                                "roomId": 822808201,
                                "policygroupId": 346547507,
                                "mealplan": 2,
                                "channel": 581,
                                "currencyId": 2,
                                "maxPersons": 3,
                                "flags": 0,
                                "freeCancelUntil": 0,
                                "priceBase10Exponent": -2,
                                "packageId": 0,
                                "paymenttermsId": 38,
                                "vrFlags": 0,
                                "bundleId": 0
                            },
                            "blockStay": {
                                "stayNights": [
                                    {
                                        "polId": 346547507,
                                        "rateId": 25728208,
                                        "curId": 2,
                                        "price": 344.25,
                                        "price1": 0,
                                        "channelId": 581,
                                        "occupancy": 2,
                                        "roomId": 822808201,
                                        "initialPrice": 405,
                                        "initialPrice1": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "stayNrRooms": 1,
                                "stayAvailableUntil": 1956105,
                                "stayPrice": 344.25,
                                "stayFlashDeal": 0,
                                "stayPromoTextId": 0,
                                "stayMinAdvanceRes": 1673388000,
                                "stayInventorySegmentId": 0,
                                "stayExperimentFlags": 0,
                                "stayRoomRateFlags": 4,
                                "stayIncludedProducts": 0
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    "selectedBlocks": [
                        "822808201_346547507_2_2_0"
                    ],
                    "selected": {
                        "822808201_346547507_2_2_0": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "pipeline": 3
}
```

Here I flagged severval keys I'd like to replace with **'==> (new key)'**

```
jq '.. | keys?' star-dragongate.json 
[
  "hits",
  "pipeline",
  "requestContext",
  "requestTopic",
  "searchQuery",
  "showDebug", ==> showdebug 
  "timeoutMs"
]
[
  "adultsTotal",
  "checkin",
  "checkout",
  "childrenTotal",
  "currency",
  "numberRoomsNeeded"
]
[
  "action",
  "affiliateId", ==> Affilateid
  "currency",
  "detectedUserType",
  "enableExperiments",
  "starSettings",
  "includeConditional",
  "isCsRelocationMode",
  "isInternal",
  "isUserstar",
  "languageCode",
  "paymentTiming",
  "serverRole",
  "shouldTrackRequestInExperiments", ==> inexperiments
  "siteType",
  "siteTypeId",
  "trafficSourceId",
  "travelPurpose",
  "tripValueContext",
  "userAuthLevel",
  "userId",
  "visitorCc1",
  "visitorCountryRegion",
  "visitorIdentifier"
]
[
  0,
  1,
  2
]
[
  "type",
  "uvi"
]
[
  "type",
  "uvi"
]
[
  "type",
  "uvi"
]
[
  "canStarUserSeeFreeBreakfast",
  "canStarUserSeeFreeCleaningFee",
  "canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade",  ==> freeroom_upgrade
  "starDynamicPricing",
  "starTier",
  "starVipSettings",
  "isRightstar",
  "isUserstar",
  "isUserstarControlGroup",
  "topstarBenefit"
]
[
  "canSeestarDynamicPricingLevel3"
]
[
  0
]
[
  "benefitName",
  "eligible",
  "percentage",
  "programType"
]
[]
[
  0
]
[
  "hhhhid",
  "ppblock",
  "selected",
  "selectedBlocks"
]
[
  "allMatchingBlocks"
]
[
  0
]
[
  "blockId",
  "blockStay",
  "rawBlock"
]
[
  "bundleId",  ==> bundle_id
  "channel",
  "currencyId",
  "flags",
  "freeCancelUntil",
  "maxPersons",
  "mealplan",
  "occupancy",
  "packageId",
  "paymenttermsId",
  "policygroupId",
  "price",
  "priceBase10Exponent",
  "roomId",
  "vrFlags"
]
[
  "stayAvailableUntil",
  "stayExperimentFlags",
  "stayFlashDeal",
  "stayIncludedProducts",
  "stayInventorySegmentId",
  "stayMinAdvanceRes",
  "stayNights",
  "stayNrRooms",
  "stayPrice",
  "stayPromoTextId", ==> staypromotextid
  "stayRoomRateFlags"
]
[
  0
]
[
  "channelId",
  "curId",
  "initialPrice",
  "initialPrice1",
  "occupancy",
  "polId",
  "price",
  "price1",
  "rateId",
  "roomId"
]
[
  0
]
[
  "822808201_346547507_2_2_0"
]
```

The keys I need to replace located in different embed layer and blocks of this json.
Is there any suggestion on how to replace those keys in an efficient way ?
PS: The keys in json file are in static location, not dymanically change all the time.

Comment: Can you be more specific on "replace some keys" and "those I need"?

Comment: jq or gojq would no doubt be a good choice, but if you want a more specific answer, you'll have to be a bit more specific about your requirements.  Please also bear in mind that you can almost always give one or two brief examples to illustrate the requirements.  In any case, please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Comment: What do you want to replace? Can you reduce your example to a _minimal_ [mre]? And then share the expected output too? How do you want to replace the values? Compute a new value based on the current one or replace with a constant value?

Comment: @pmf I have updated my question with your suggested part added , thank you for your feedbacks!

Comment: This still isn't exactly minimal. You only need a few extraneous pieces of data to specify that things that aren't your target remain untouched; not tens or hundreds of lines of such.

Comment: And pointers to the things you want to change doesn't specify the most important thing, which is _how you want your code to find them_. Code to search by location is different from code to search by exact string match is different from code to search by substring, etc.

Comment: For example, if you just want a recursive find-and-replaced based on exact textual matching (which is exactly what it looks like to me here), that's a question that's already asked and answered elsewhere in our knowledge base!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename a field name, you could use `with_entries`, which gives you access to each `.key`. Reset it by assignment.

Now, what's still unclear is how you want to find the keys in question (programmatically). If their locations are static, and you know them, address them individually, as in:

```bash
.requestContext.starSettings |= with_entries((.key | select(. == "canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade")) = "freeroom_upgrade")
| .hits[].ppblock.allMatchingBlocks[].rawBlock |= with_entries((.key | select(. == "bundleId")) = "bundle_id")
# and so on...
```

To reduce redundant code, you could also move the renaming portion of it into its own function, and then just call that, e.g.:

```bash
def rename($old; $new):
  with_entries((.key | select(. == $old)) = $new);

.requestContext.starSettings |= rename("canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade"; "freeroom_upgrade")
| .hits[].ppblock.allMatchingBlocks[].rawBlock |= rename("bundleId";  "bundle_id")
# and so on...
```

Or move the location also into the function, e.g.:

```bash
def rename_at(path; $old; $new):
  path |= with_entries((.key | select(. == $old)) = $new);

rename_at(.requestContext.starSettings; "canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade"; "freeroom_upgrade")
| rename_at(.hits[].ppblock.allMatchingBlocks[].rawBlock; "bundleId";  "bundle_id")
# and so on...
```

If their location is unknown, and you want to replace them just based on their (local) name, you need to traverse the document, and check if you hit a matching name. The `walk` function provides you with the traversal, `objects` reduces the action to objects:

```bash
walk(objects |= with_entries(
  if .key == "canStarUserSeeFreeRoomUpgrade" then .key = "freeroom_upgrade"
  elif .key == "bundleId" then .key = "bundle_id"
  # and so on...
  else . end
))
```

Comment: hello pmf , I updated my post again , yes , all my keys and json file is located in static location, not changing dynamically , thanks for your answer and suggestion

Comment: I have added a second example to each, to cover the use of arrays in the path.